# How can I remove two consecutive prints made in windows command prompt?

Tags: python

I'm using Python 2.7 in Window's command prompt window (this is important since it means I can't handle VT100 escape sequences).

To erase the previous line in the console I can use `sys.stdout.write('\r'+white_spaces_covering_the_entire_text`.
But what if I want to erase the last *n* prints instead of only the last print?

Let's make an example:

```
import sys
import time

print(" Some text goes here\n")
print(" Some other text goes here\n")

print(" Calculating something. Please wait until it is done.")
for x in range(10):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    sys.stdout.write('\r'+" "*20)
    sys.stdout.write('\r'+" Loading"+"."*x)


sys.stdout.write('\r'+" "*20)

print(" We have concluded that blah blah blah")
```

As you can see there is a part where the "Loading" print is overwritten as to "animate" the line.

After the long wait (5 seconds) the program ends and the command window will look like this:

```
 Some text goes here

 Some other text goes here

 Calculating something. Please wait until it is done.
 We have concluded that blah blah blah
```

The idea here is that I would like to remove the "Calculating something. Please wait until it is done." line (not only the last "Loading.........." print). This means to remove the last two lines. How can I do it?

I discovered a very ugly (but working) aproach to solve this. This code does what I needed:

```
import sys
import time
import os

def cls():
    os.system('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear')

print(" Some text goes here\n")
print(" Some other text goes here\n")

print(" Calculating something. Please wait until it is done.")
for x in range(10):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    sys.stdout.write('\r'+" "*20)
    sys.stdout.write('\r'+" Loading"+"."*x)

cls()

print(" Some text goes here\n")
print(" Some other text goes here\n")

print(" We have concluded that blah blah blah")
```

But this is terrible. As you can see I needed 5 new lines of code, refresh the entire window and repeat some lines. If the program was long enough it would be very painfull to save each printed text in a variable to display all as it was before clearing the entire window. Also clearing the window works but if the command window was full of prints then the load would be noticiable while reprinting all that was before the lines we wanted to change.

What is the most elegant way to tackle this problem? Is there any way to erase a specific line in the command window? Or maybe a pythonian way to erase the last *n* lines?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to erase the last n lines:

```
for i in range(n):
    sys.stdout.write("\033[F") #Cursor up one line
    sys.stdout.write("\033[K") #Erase this line
```